# How to show space key in softkeyboard and perform some action when user clicks on space key

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edittext. In that edittext user enters some text. when user hits on space key, i need to  perform some action. how can i do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To do something when the user presses the space key you use the following -

```
if((event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&(key == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)){
//put your code for whatever you what to do when the user presses space here
   }
}
```

[Problems intercepting space key in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302483/problems-intercepting-space-key-in-edittext)

If you have multiple edittexts, in the above code put

```
if (edittext.hasFocus()){
    //do something for particular edit text
}
```

I think I know why your edittext is not working. When the edittext is focused(selected), the key clicks are bypassing your activity and go in straight to the edittext. To solve this you need to move the `onKeyListener` into an `onKeyListener` for your edittext.

Try the below code instead

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {           
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int key, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && key == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                //operation that you want on key press
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hope this one helps

Comment: ya i have done the same but it is not working for softkeyboard

Comment: Are you sure that that is the part that isn't working? Try putting  something like `finish()` in the key listener to check

Comment: editText1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
 
   public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      
          if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
              (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)) {
            
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, editText1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
          }
          return false;
      }
  });

Comment: it is working when i press space key on my system keyboard but it is not working for softkeyboard

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to use `TextWatcher` for EditText. and you can implement in this way

```
 EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
              // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                int start, int count, int after)
        {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                int start, int before, int count)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
            if(s.toString().equals(" "))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Space is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this surely useful to you when user click space button define your own action...

```
youredittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)) {
                  // Perform action on key press

                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), youredittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```