# onKey event for editText not firing

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm having a really hard time getting the OnKey event to trigger on my EditText view. I've been Googling for over an hour now and it seems everyone says all you have to do is add a OnKeyListener to the view but it's not triggering it. I tried adding it to the entire Activity and also tried adding it to the view itself but neither way is triggering the function.

My code:

XML:

```
 <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/interests_editText" />
```

Java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_post);

    interests_editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.interests_editText);
    interests_editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

               public boolean onKey(    View view,    int keyCode,    KeyEvent event){
                   Log.i("DEBUG","TeST");
                   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                       return true;
                   }
                   else {
                       return false;
                   }
               }
           }
    );
```

**Update:** 
My final goal is to get it to recognize when you press space while in that editText view. I added to the XML

```
android:inputType="text"
```

and then changed the code to

```
public boolean onKey(    View view,    int keyCode,    KeyEvent event){
                   Log.i("DEBUG","Outside");
                   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
                       Log.i("DEBUG","Space");
                       return true;
                   }
                   else {
                       return false;
                   }
```

Now the keyboard shows a Next button that when pressed logs "Outside" but it doesn't log "Space"

Answer (score 1):

Do you wanna capture Enter event? If so, try `setOnEditorActionListener`

For your Update Info: capture space key, try `addTextChangedListener`

Comment: I want to capture while typing in this field if they press Space.

Comment: Okay I added that and now I can log when the text is changed but how do I tell if it was a space that was entered last?

Comment: You can find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393121/how-to-show-space-key-in-softkeyboard-and-perform-some-action-when-user-clicks-o (Ram kiran's answer). Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you - you directed me towards solving my question. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @BNK's answer I got it to work using the following code:

```
interests_editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    String str = s.toString();
    if(str.substring(str.length()-1, str.length()).equals(" "))
        Log.i("DEBUG","Space pressed");
    else if(str.substring(str.length()-1, str.length()).equals("\n"))
        Log.i("DEBUG", "Enter pressed");
    else
        Log.i("DEBUG", "Pressed : " +str.substring(str.length()-1, str.length()) );
}}
```